# How to initialize an edittext in a dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to instantiate an EditText inside of a DialogFragment onCreateDialog after inflating the Layout. Note: The EditText is already part of the LinearLayout being inflated in setView.

```
public class UserEntryDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_dialog, null));

//        EditText userEntryEditText;
//        userEntryEditText = userEntryEditText.findViewById(R.id.entryDialogEditText); - may not have been initalized
//        final EditText userEntryEditText = (EditText) userEntryEditText.findViewById(R.id.entryDialogEditText); - variable may not have been initiized
//        final EditText = new EditText(); - not a valid constructor
//        final EditText = new (EditText) userEntryEditText.findViewById(R.id.entryDialogEditText); - cannot resolve symbol userEntryText
//        EditText userEntryEditText = new userEntryEditText.findViewWithTag("edittexttag"); - findViewWithTag not a method
//        inflater.inflate(R.id.entryDialogEditText, null); - requires a layout argument

    userEntryEditText.requestFocus();
```

additional code...

```
}
```

Again, I want an EditText that I can then later use to getText. I hope that you can help out.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

As you arent doing anything special while creating the dialogue i would recommend removing your override code and use this code snipped instead.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_dialog, container, false);
    EditText ev = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    return v;
}
```

so either remove you code above, ore replace it by this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}
```